# In what way is this jStorage Object different and why?

Tags: jquery, object, jstorage

I am working on an e-shop, where an item inserted into basket gets inserted into jStorage key named `BasketItemNumber_I` [where I is an int and every other item gets i++ in a name].

example: BasketItemNumber_1, BasketItemNumber_2, etc..

Now, my client asked me to add an input, in which the number of pieces of an item will be, so that client can change the int without needing to use + 1 and - 1 functions.

Let's say I've got one item inside the basket. When I echo this item in console, it looks like this:

[image: Console echo in Chrome before the change]

Now, the goal is to change the piece value of an object to the one user has written into the input, therefore the item has an onfocusout function that looks like this:

```
function onFocusOutFunction(jStorageItemName, i) {

console.log(jStorageItemName + " Focus Out");
var jStorageFocusedOutBasketPiece =  $.jStorage.get(jStorageItemName);

console.log("jStorageFocusedOutBasketPiece: " + jStorageFocusedOutBasketPiece[0].piece);
var inputFocusedOutBasketPiece = document.getElementById('pieceInput_' + i).value;
inputFocusedOutBasketPiece = inputFocusedOutBasketPiece.replace(/\D/g,'');
console.log("inputFocusedOutBasketPiece: " + inputFocusedOutBasketPiece);

function isNumber(obj) { return !isNaN(parseFloat(obj)) }

console.log(isNumber(inputFocusedOutBasketPiece));


if (inputFocusedOutBasketPiece == jStorageFocusedOutBasketPiece[0].piece){
  console.log("Values are the same");
}else {

  console.log("Values are not the same, therefore piece value will be changed");

  console.log("Before change");
  console.log(jStorageFocusedOutBasketPiece);

  jStorageFocusedOutBasketPiece[0].piece = parseInt(inputFocusedOutBasketPiece);

  $.jStorage.set(jStorageItemName, jStorageFocusedOutBasketPiece[0]);
  $.jStorage.setTTL(jStorageItemName, 604800000);

  console.log("After the change");
  console.log(jStorageFocusedOutBasketPiece);

  console.log("After jStorage set");
  console.log(jStorageItemName);
  console.log($.jStorage.get(jStorageItemName));

  window.location.assign('basket.php');

}

}
```

But, whenever I change the value (so that this function can do it's thing). The output of the BasketItemNumber_1 looks like this:

[image: Console echo in Chrome after the change]

The item is not listed in the basket anymore since I have to check it with this portion of the code: (I know I use eval and that is a bad practice, I plan on changing this later on, now I need to finish the proof of concept, not the actual product).

```
for (var i = 1, len = jStorageIndex.length; i < len; i++){


jStorageItemContents =  eval("$.jStorage.get('BasketItemNumber_" + i + "')");
jStorageItemName     = "BasketItemNumber_" + i


if (typeof jStorageItemContents == "undefined" || !    (jStorageItemContents instanceof Array)) {

console.log("An array is empty, skipping.");

}else {


if(jStorageItemContents[0].active == "true"){
```

... and so on.

basically, i do not see an item, but i see "An array is empty, skipping" in the console.

I have to use the logic above, since sometime the BasketItems are empty (after user deletes them, their empty arrays stay in the cache sometimes) therefore I only want to display those that actually include something.

Therefore I have to ask: what, how and why exactly changed the way an Object is represented?

I see the difference is in the way they are being outputed in the console, more specifically in the [] and {}, but I do not understand, what has made that change possible and how to proceed:

I would rather change the way an Object is represented after the change of the piece value to match the format it once had, so that I do not have to mess with the typeof logic above, since there are other things that depend on it as well.

Note: there is also a + and - button, that change the piece value respectively.

These functions are:

```
$(document).on('click', '#addPieceButton', function(){

var variable = $(this).attr('itemname');
var variable = variable.toString();

var basketItem = $.jStorage.get(variable);


basketItem[0].piece = parseInt(basketItem[0].piece) + 1;
console.log(basketItem[0].piece);

  $.jStorage.set(variable, basketItem);
  $.jStorage.setTTL(variable, 604800000);

  console.log($.jStorage.get(variable));

     location.reload(true);




});

$(document).on('click', '#removePieceButton', function(){

 var variable = $(this).attr('itemname');
 var variable = variable.toString();

 var basketItem = $.jStorage.get(variable);

basketItem[0].piece = parseInt(basketItem[0].piece) - 1;

if(basketItem[0].piece == 0){ //If there is 0, we will show the warning

    if (window.confirm("By changing the pieces to 0 the item will disappear? Do you want to continue?")) {

      //This will change the active to false, thanks to which it will be no longer displayed
      for (var i in basketItem) {
        if (basketItem[i].active == "true") {
          basketItem[i].active = "false";
          break; //Stop this loop, we've found it!
     }
  }
      $.jStorage.set(variable, basketItem);
      $.jStorage.setTTL(variable, 604800000);

      console.log($.jStorage.get(variable));

         location.reload(true);

  }
  else {
    console.log("User answered NO");
    location.reload(true);
  }

}else {


console.log(basketItem[0].piece);

  $.jStorage.set(variable, basketItem);
  $.jStorage.setTTL(variable, 604800000);

  console.log($.jStorage.get(variable));

     location.reload(true);


   }
});
```

and they work perfectly. By writing this down, I somehow feel the reason will be somewhere in the fact that I do not use jQuery for the function I have problem with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, when you're saving the new item after the changes, you're overwriting the original array and putting in the element at index 0 (at the following line):

```
$.jStorage.set(jStorageItemName, jStorageFocusedOutBasketPiece[0]);
```

This is why it stops being an array at this point.
You might want to only replace the relevant item in the storage, and set the whole array again. Simply eliminate the index:

```
$.jStorage.set(jStorageItemName, jStorageFocusedOutBasketPiece);
```

What's happening is that you used to have a list of items, and you rewrote it to be only the first out of these items later on.

**Side Note:**
You're right about eval, and frankly there's no reason for you not to eliminate it immediately. Simply replace that part with this:

```
jStorageItemName = 'BasketItemNumber_' + i;
jStorageItemContents = $.jStorage.get(jStorageItemName);
```